# RabbitMQ Spring Boot Session Error

Tags: spring, neo4j, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-data-neo4j

I am running into an issue when trying to pass a RabbitMQ queue message to my Spring Boot application. I am running spring data 4 and am using Neo4j as my database. I am able to recieve and parse a JSON string from the RabbitMQ queue to the spring boot app. Here is the thread change for the receiver process:

`14:19:17.811 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
14:19:17.813 [main] INFO  org.directoryx.Application - Started Application in 4.989 seconds (JVM running for 5.47)
14:19:26.708 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  org.directoryx.sync.Receiver - Message Recv'd! {"lastName":"Okuneva", "country":"United States", "city":"New Stantonfort","org":"IT","photo":"profile9.jpg",
"active":"true", "managerId":"1502", "title":"Global Integration Orchestrator", "userId":"frokune", "firstName":"Frank",
"phone":"(485)544-1782 x913", "id":"6791", "email":"frokune@peoplemaker.com","status":"Employee"}
14:19:26.718 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  org.directoryx.sync.Receiver - Update Person: Frank Okuneva`

but when I try to save the incoming JSON into a Neo4j node, the application crashes with the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'receiver': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate`

Before implementing the neo4jTemplate I was getting this error when I tried to save the person through my personService->personServiceImpl->personRepository pattern.

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.getSession': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`

Here are the three classes involved:

**Receiver.java**

```
@Service
public class Receiver implements MessageListener {

static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

// Fails to be injected...
// Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
// org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:
@Autowired
private Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate;

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    Gson gson  = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String msg = new String(message.getBody());
    log.info("Message Recv'd! {}",msg);

    Person person = gson.fromJson(msg, Person.class);
    log.info("Update Person: {} {}", person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName());

    try {
        neo4jTemplate.save(person);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Receiver failed to save Person: {}", e);
    }
}
```

**DataSyncConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class DataSyncConfig {


@Autowired
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
private final String QUEUE_NAME = "sync2";
private final String ROUTING_KEY = "routeme";
private final boolean DURABLE = true;
private final boolean EXCLUSIVE = true;
private final boolean AUTO_DELETE = true;

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME, DURABLE, !EXCLUSIVE, !AUTO_DELETE);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("etl-sync-tool");
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(ROUTING_KEY);
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new JsonMessageConverter();
    return jsonMessageConverter;
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver);
}
}
```

**Neo4jConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.directoryx.repository", queryLookupStrategy = QueryLookupStrategy.Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Neo4jConfig.class);

@Resource
public Environment env;

@Override
@Bean
public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    log.info("Initialising Neo4j server connection...");

    // username and password need to be available as System properties for Neo4j authentication.
    String user = env.getProperty("neo4j.user");
    System.setProperty("username", user);

    String pass = env.getProperty("neo4j.pass");
    System.setProperty("password", pass);

    log.info("connecting as neo4j.user=" + user);
    return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474");
}

@Override
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    log.info("Initialising Session Factory");
    return new SessionFactory("org.directoryx.domain");
}

@Override
@Bean
// Unsure of scope value, tried both "session" and "global"
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    log.info("Initialising session-scoped Session Bean");
    return super.getSession();
}

@Bean
public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate (Session session ) {
    return new Neo4jTemplate(session);
}
}
```

I can't seem to find out how to save the data to the db either by exposing and using the current thread or by creating a new thread. I feel that this is an issue that shouldn't be far off from some of the core functionality of Spring Boot and Spring Data, but I cant seem to determine what syntax to use even after extensive research.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message suggests that running with a session scope isn't appropriate in your usage context, probably because you're in a RabbitMQ context as opposed to a Spring Web/MVC one.

I'd advise removing the `@Scope` annotation altogether from your `getSession` method in `Neo4jConfig` and see if that improves things.  You can always add a user-managed scope later if you feel it's necessary to do so.

In addition, you may want to consider coding against `Neo4jOperations` instead of `Neo4jTemplate`.  Some users have reported problems with injecting the class instead of the interface.

Comment: Isn't the @Scope annotation necessary? I followed the spring data tutorial a while back that specified it. https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-university/blob/master/src/main/java/school/Application.java

Comment: It's not necessary, no.  You get what Spring likes to call "prototype" scope by default, I think.

Comment: When I remove it I get this error `Error:(27, 8) java: org.directoryx.Neo4jConfig is not abstract and does not override abstract method getSessionFactory() in org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration` when attempting to run

Comment: That's a compiler error.  You wouldn't get that from just removing an annotation, surely.  Are you absolutely certain you just deleted the `@Scope` annotation from the overridden `getSession()` method?  In fact, you should be able to get rid of the `getSession()` method altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the @Scope annotation block and retained the overridden SessionFactory.

**Neoj4Config.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.directoryx.repository",   queryLookupStrategy = QueryLookupStrategy.Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Neo4jConfig.class);

@Resource
public Environment env;

@Override
@Bean
public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    log.info("Initialising Neo4j server connection...");

    // username and password need to be available as System properties for Neo4j authentication.
    String user = env.getProperty("neo4j.user");
    System.setProperty("username", user);

    String pass = env.getProperty("neo4j.pass");
    System.setProperty("password", pass);

    log.info("connecting as neo4j.user=" + user);
    return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474");
}

@Override
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    log.info("Initialising Session Factory");
    return new SessionFactory("org.directoryx.domain");
}
}
```

Comment: Good stuff - glad to have helped!