# Using Spring Data Session bean in async task. Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have the next flow to be implemented in my Spring MVC web app:

- user inserts some value on the page, i.e. makes POST to the server
- based on this value, controller starts a long running background task, i.e. really heavy (about one hour or so), so async is absolutely needed.
- during this task, it is needed to read/write to database (in my case it is Neo4j)

**How did I make it:**

1. we have bean in scope 'session':

```java
@Bean
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    return super.getSession();
}
```

2. In my controller I have some db repositories:

```java
@Autowired
SomeDBRepo repo;
```

3. I have a method, annotated by @Async

```java
@Async 
doSomeAsync() {
   repo.findAll();
}
```

**and I am getting this error:**

`Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.getSession': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`

I have already read some articles about this issue, but nothing helped to me. How this problem could be solved?

Comment: Did you add @EnableAsync to a configuration class?

Comment: And I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31574551) will help you...

Comment: Yes, I added @EnableAsync

Comment: Why do you need scope session in the long running task? can't it be just a singleton?

Comment: Which version of SDN are you using? There is no longer any need to declare the Session bean. Please use 4.2.4 and refer to this documentation for configuration: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/

You should find that @Async requests work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The session and request scopes in Spring are thread bound.

When you annotate a method with `@Async` the execution takes place in another thread, and cannot access the scopes of the caller (and thus the session).

Try to inject the `SessionFactory` in your async bean to get a Session.

BTW, are you sure you really need a session scope ? This stores the OGM session in the web session, which can lead to memory problems under load, as the session acts as a first level cache of the database.